# Can't Save SQL Query in 2sxc SQL DataSource

Tags: sql, sql-server, dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I'm trying to use the *DNN SQL DataSource* in 2sxc's VisualQuery Designer to retrieve and display information from SQL in a 2sxc App. However, when I try to input my SQL query and click 'Save', a 403 error is displayed. I was unable to find the 2sxc error log. Is there something wrong with my SQL query? How can I get the datasource to accept my query?

**SQL Query:**

*Note: some values have been modified for privacy.*

```
SELECT Description, CanonicalURL,
(CASE WHEN CanonicalURL LIKE '/abc/%' THEN CanonicalURL ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Replace(TabPath, '//', '/') FROM Tabs WHERE TabName = PageName AND TabPath LIKE '//abc//%') END) AS 'abc',
(CASE WHEN CanonicalURL LIKE '/def/%' THEN CanonicalURL ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Replace(TabPath, '//', '/') FROM Tabs WHERE TabName = PageName AND TabPath LIKE '//def//%') END) AS 'def',
(CASE WHEN CanonicalURL LIKE '/ghi/%' THEN CanonicalURL ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Replace(TabPath, '//', '/') from Tabs WHERE TabName = PageName AND TabPath LIKE '//ghi//%') END) as 'ghi'
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.Description, Replace(TabPath, '//', '/') + '/' + PageName as 'CanonicalURL', PageName
    FROM [dbo].[My_Series_Tabs] cst
    JOIN My_SeriesContent s ON cst.SerieID = s.SeriesID
    JOIN Tabs t ON t.TabID = cst.tabID
    WHERE PageName IS NOT NULL AND TargetCanonicalURL = 1 AND TabPath NOT LIKE '%translated%' AND CultureCode = 'en-US') allseries
```

**403 Error**

Had an error talking to the server (status 403)

Comment: Also you should not use string literals to name columns (e.g.: `as 'PageName'`), use square brackets instead (e.g.: `as [PageName]`) or double quotes (e.g.: `as "PageName"`).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the feedback! I've updated the quotes around the column names to brackets as suggested. However, this did not allow me to save the query within the 2sxc dialog. Also, I don't need the data in the `TabName` and `TabPath` columns. The query returns all the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

Saving happens as API calls and you should be able to see them in the insights logs. Best check that and post the lines where it errors here, so we can help more.